# Connecting more than 2 V2 camera modules

Tags: camera

I am trying to find out how to connect more than 2 x V2 8Mb camera modules to the Raspberry Pi 3b module so that I can have 3 images at once on a display screen.

Comment: What's your question? I don't see a question mark in your post at all!

Answer (score -1):

You can buy a multi CSI adapter to use more than 1 the official camera like this [multi-camera-adapter](https://www.iot-store.com.au/products/multi-camera-adapter-module-fully-compatible-for-official-raspberry-pi-board) which there are a few different makers / designs which allow multiple CSI inputs into a single port on the Raspberry Pi.

Another approach is to use multiple USB cameras, which would probably be cheaper.

Comment: Can you edit this post? i have to many pending edits and i downvoted (not on purpose) ment to upvote!